# Install/Upgrade bash using Nix under macOS Catalina

Tags: bash, shell, macos

I'm using macOS `Catalina` and Nix `2.3.12`.

I'm updating `bash` to the latest version (via Nix). I can successfully install it, and it loads the version installed by Nix, but if I try to use any feature from Bash `5.x` (the updated version) I'm unable to unless `.bashrc` is sourced — which is what in turns sources Nix.

I source `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile` (which contains only this):

```bsh
#
# ~/.bash_profile
#

[ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] && . "${HOME}/.bashrc"
```

Is there a way to load the updated version right before all of that happens?

Even if I update `/etc/shells` file with the newer `bash` location and try to do `chsh -s /Users/x80486/.nix-profile/bin/bash` it doesn't work.

---

This is the content of my `.bashrc` file:

```bsh
#
# ~/.bashrc
#

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return

# Aliases
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ -f "${HOME}/.bash_aliases" ] && . "${HOME}/.bash_aliases"

# Check the window size after each command and, if necessary, update the
# values of LINES and COLUMNS
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
shopt -s checkwinsize

# Append to the history file, don't overwrite it
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
shopt -s histappend

# Prompt customization
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PS1="\[$(tput sgr0)\][\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[$(tput sgr0)\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[$(tput sgr0)\]]$ "
# PS1="[\u@\h \W]$ "
export PS1

# Set default editor
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano
export EDITOR

# Set default blocksize for ls, df, du
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BLOCKSIZE=1k
export BLOCKSIZE

# Do not log repeated identical commands
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
export HISTCONTROL

# Increase/Set history limit (100 KB or 5000 entries)
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HISTFILESIZE=100000
export HISTFILESIZE
HISTSIZE=100
export HISTSIZE

# Erlang
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# export ERL_AFLAGS="+pc unicode -kernel shell_history enabled"

# Golang
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GOPATH="${HOME}/.cache/go-path"
export GOPATH

[ ! -d "${HOME}/.cache/go-path" ] && mkdir --parents "${HOME}/.cache/go-path"
PATH="${PATH}:${GOPATH}/bin"

# Nix Package Manager
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR="${HOME}/.nix-profile/etc/bash_completion.d"
export BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR
XDG_DATA_DIRS="${HOME}/.nix-profile/share:${XDG_DATA_DIRS}"
export XDG_DATA_DIRS

[ -f "${HOME}/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh" ] && . "${HOME}/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh"
[ -f "${HOME}/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ] && . "${HOME}/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh"
[ -f "${HOME}/.nix-profile/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash" ] && . "${HOME}/.nix-profile/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash"
[ -f "${HOME}/.nix-profile/share/bash-completion/completions/gradle" ] && . "${HOME}/.nix-profile/share/bash-completion/completions/gradle"

# Playground Area
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# ASDF
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ -f "${HOME}/.asdf/asdf.sh" ] && . "${HOME}/.asdf/asdf.sh"
[ -f "${HOME}/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash" ] && . "${HOME}/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash"

export PATH
```

Comment: What doesn't work about `chsh -s /Users/x80486/.nix-profile/bin/bash`?  That is the right way to change your default shell on macos.  Does it error?

Comment: Also what is your `.bashrc` doing to set your shell?  Whatever it is it probably shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: @jesse_b, I'm not setting the shell inside `.bashrc`. I just happen to have an `mkdir --parents ../` command that is not valid under `bash 3.x`. Moreover, if I don't rollback `chsh -s /Users/x80486/.nix-profile/bin/bash` I get some error messages initially: `-bash: shopt: progcomp: invalid shell option name` and the prompt is completely borked.

Comment: Forgot to mention that `/Users/x80486/.nix-profile/bin/bash` is a system link to the actual location where `Nix` installs its packages...not sure if that could be a problem.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem with MacOS 13.4 and Nix 2.17 + nix-darwin. Has anyone fixed this?